# Парсинг товаров Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Всем доброго времени суток. Мне необходимо спарсить и обновлять каждый день 40к+ товаров. Сейчас использую Octolooks Scrapes, но из-за него большая нагрузка на хост. Хотелось бы получить советов, как реализовать правильно.

Comment: Я недавно делал заказ по парсингу wc магаза. Я использовал python, делал по этому [гайду](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykjBVT57r68). Я не спец в питоне конечно, но все вышло на 100%

Comment: SO не тот ресурс чтобы просить советов. Но правильно не парсить, а  работать с API

Comment: Какой смысл парсить свой сайт?

Comment: А где сказано про парсинг собственного сайта? Парсится сбремаркет